# Voltage vs Current for DC electronics?

Tags: voltage, power, current

I have a choice of voltage (6VDC, 12VDC or 24VDC) to power a solenoid component rated at around 2.5W.

Depending on different voltages, it will result in different current consumption (ie. I@6VDC = 2.5/6 = 0.417A)

I will have a grid of 100 solenoid devices powered via a single external power supply (reverse current protected). This means that other components will not be impacted by my voltage & power solution.

If in the end of the day, the energy is consumed in Watt-hours, what are the reasons why one would go for 6V, 12V or 24V?

Comment: Do you have a link to the datasheet?

Comment: So 100 devices at 2.5 W each that's 250 W. Even at 24 V the total current will be more than 10 A. That's already a lot of current. Going to a lower voltage (and thus higher current) will make things even less efficient.

Comment: Another off-topic thing is, by using a single power supply you are creating a single point of failure. You might want to re-consider that.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie the complete set will be only running for 10-15 minutes a day. Also, the solenoids are driven by short voltage impulses (1-3 seconds apart) rather continuous load. When you say "a lot of current" - in what way do you rate it as a lot?

Comment: 10-15 minutes a day does not mean much in the sense that this would suddenly change anything. I was assuming all devices could be activated all at once since you did not mention otherwise. A lot of current means that the current (10A) is such that you will need to make sure all the connections where 10 A can flow need to be capable of handling that. There are tables that tell you how thick a cable's core must be for that current. Suffice to say that standard cheap wire as used in many electronics projects **cannot** handle 10 A.

Answer (score 1):

Relays come in different voltages and typically, for any given family, the power rating and switching performance is basically the same regardless of the voltage. As such, which one you chose will come down to other factors.

Rail availability. This is often the prime mover when you are only using one or a small number of relays. In this case it is prudent to find a relay that uses a power rail that your system already has rather than adding the cost of a new power supply.

Current Distribution. If you have a significant number of relays then distributing the currents involved becomes an issue. If you use low voltage relays, not only do you need a beefy expensive power supply, but you also need to have heavy wiring or even solid bus-bars to effectively carry the required current to the farthest relay, under all conditions, without incurring so much voltage loss that the relay no longer performs reliably.

Comment: In my case, I would be using Darlington Transistor Arrays (uln2803) instead of relays. It allows me to drive the solenoids via external power supply while controlling via 5VDC logic signals. Also - the project currently is not meant for mass production, so the cost optimization is probably not the top priority at the moment. It's rather risk & safety I care most about.

Comment: @ArtursVancans whichever... just be aware of your voltage drops and risers... both on the rail and the grounds.

Comment: thank you. Just to summarize - one of the main concerns is if my current demand is high, then it will require beefy cables as it will increase the heating and reduce the overall efficiency, correct? If my total draw is 10A, I could use more than one power supply to minimize the load on the copper?

Comment: @ArtursVancans efficiency is a dangerous road to go down discussion wise since it depends on conductor sizes. Ensuring voltage drops are small is however critical to operational performance.

Answer (score 0):

With 24V, you get 2.5/24 ~ 0.1A. Lesser the current, lesser the resistive losses or resistive heating in the solenoid coil, lesser wear and tear of the device. But for the best results, referring to datasheet instructions is important.

Comment: The datasheet is almost non-existent. I got the solenoids from Alibaba, and the datasheet only consists of dimensions, resistance, power rating and some pull/release timing.  So are you saying, that the only disadvantage for choosing lesser voltage is that it will make the circuit less efficient by producing more heat on the wires? (the actual solenoids are going to be powered with 20-50ms impulses with 1-3 sec delay between)

Comment: Is there a formula for that? Joule heating is (I*V) same as for power so regardless of what values are chosen it will produce the same heating - I must be missing something

Comment: Please indicate what the coil resistance is, that will accurately give you the current for every voltage. Because the resistance is kind of a constant property of the coil. Using those respective currents determine the power losses at those voltages. Use the voltage which gives you minimum power loss. You may think that 2.5W is going to be constant. But it is dependent on the voltage you apply and is the rated power of coil. Doesn't mean it is always 2.5W. You need two known variables to get the third unknown in P=V^2*R.

Comment: And heating is one of the important factors, you may also have to look for available power supplies with that kind of voltage and current capacity.

Comment: @AmyM, minor correction: P = V*I. For a resistor, it's \$V^2/R\$ or \$I^2R\$.

Comment: @ThePhoton oops...you are right, thank you! But I don't know why I cant edit my comment!

Comment: @AmyM, comments are only editable for a minute or two. In any case, it's a minor error and doesn't invalidate the rest of your comment.